# Does iptables affect existing tcp flows

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm trying to emulate a network partition via `iptables -I INPUT -s <other-ip-address> -j DROP` on both nodes.

Will this affect existing tcp flows, or will it only affect subsequent ones (ie if the flow is restarted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'filter' table applies to every packet, regardless of flow.

Flow tracking is only done through an explicit rule that matches conntrack state, e.g. `-m state`. So if your ruleset looks like this (as shown by iptables-save):

```
-A INPUT -s <client1> -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s <client2> -j DROP
```

then the 1st rule will apply to **all** packets in any flow, but the 3rd rule *will not* be reached for existing flows as they will be matched by conntrack. *(Remember that iptables chains are read from top to bottom, and the ACCEPT/DROP verdicts are final and stop processing at that point.)*

Note that you can also manually flush or delete flow states using the `conntrack` CLI tool. For example, even if the iptables ruleset has "accept established" as the very first rule, you can run `conntrack -F` to forget all flows and make them go through the entire ruleset again.

Also note that the above answer is specifically for 'filter' rules. On the other hand, rules in the 'nat' table are strongly tied to conntrack and *only* apply to packets which don't yet have a known state – i.e. the first packet of a connection goes through SNAT/DNAT rules but all further packets are automatically rewritten by conntrack.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify this means that for example `iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.1 -j DROP` will drop all incomming packets from `10.0.0.1` (in the absence of any other rules)?

Comment: `-I` inserts the rule at the top, so it will drop all incoming packets even in presence of any other rules.